# How to make a heat map of WiFi signal in Rviz?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS kinetic and tried to use wireless_watcher but it's only displaying the signal strength and I am not able to visualize it in Rviz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272934/how-to-make-a-heat-map-of-wifi-signal-in-rviz?/) by [lakshay](https://answers.ros.org/users/32228/lakshay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of a existing package that does this, but using the [grid_map](https://github.com/ethz-asl/grid_map) library it would be relatively easy to do a simple implementation, e.g. take RSSI and robot pose, add data into map. For making things appear nice and dense visually some more smoothing would be required (for instance by using [grid_map_cv](https://github.com/ethz-asl/grid_map/tree/master/grid_map_cv/include/grid_map_cv) and converting to/from opencv).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lakshay](https://answers.ros.org/users/32228/lakshay/) on 2017-11-08**:
Could you please elaborate on how to use grid_map library for the implementation part.